# AWS Batch vs Spring Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I have been planning to migrate my Batch processing from Spring Batch to AWS Batch. Can someone give me the reasons to Choose **AWS Batch** over **Spring Batch**?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question that most likely relies on opinion. I'm not sure you'll get a good answer. Could you maybe share the code you use for your batch processing and tell us what you've tried or found out about Spring Batch?

Answer (score 3):

I believe both work at different levels .Spring batch provide framework that reduce the boiler plate code that you need in order to write a batch job.For eg. saving the state of job in Job repository that provide restartability.

On the contrary, AWS batch is an infrastructure framework that helps in managing infra and set some environment variable that help differentiate master node from slave node.

In my opinion both can work together to write a full fledged cost effective batch job at scale on AWS cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst both these things will play a role in orchestrating your batch workloads a key difference is that AWS Batch will also manage the infrastructure you need to run the jobs/pipeline. AWS Batch lets you to tailor the underlying cloud instances, or specifcy a broad array of instance types that will work for you. And it'll let you make trade-offs: you can task it with managing a bag of EC2 Spot instances for you (for example), and then ask it to optimize time-to-execution over price (or prefer price to speed).

(For full disclosure, I work for the engineering team that builds AWS Batch).

Answer (score 0):

Aws Batch is full blown SaaS solution for batch processing,
It has inbuilt

- Queue with priority options
- Runtime, which can be self managed and auto managed
- Job repo, docker images for the job definitions
- Monitoring , dashboards, integration with other AWS services like SNS and from SNS to where ever you want

On the other hand,  batch is a framework which would still need some of your efforts to manage it all. like employing a queue, scaling is your headache, monitoring etc

My take is , if your company or app is on AWS , go for AWS batch , you will save months of time and get to scalability to a million jobs per day in no time . If you are on-perm or private go for spring batch with some research